# Crystal Reports dependencies on Views

Tags: crystal-reports

I have 200 crystal reports (rpt files), all reports are built by calling the VIEWS. Is there anyway that, I need to know which report is using which VIEW.

Crystal Report version 10

Example:

Employee.rpt depends on V_employee, V_office.

I don't want to open all the 200 reports to find this..please help me..!!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind doing a little programming, you could write a simple program to output all tables referenced by a report. Here is a C# sample:

```
    private void PrintTableNames(ReportDocument rpt)
    {
        foreach (Table tbl in rpt.Database.Tables)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tbl.LogOnInfo.TableName);
        }

        if (!rpt.IsSubreport)
        {
            foreach (ReportDocument subRpt in rpt.Subreports)
            {
                PrintTableNames(subRpt);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this isn't possible.  You are going to have to go through each report and see which database objects it uses.

At least next time you will know to document your reports fully so you won't have this situation again :-)